# Rails 4 - Mapping a model dynamically on two different database tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a multi domain app talking to a legacy database. 
In that DB I have two tables with different names, lets call them `USER_A` and `USER_B`. Their structure and data types are exactly the same, the only difference is that they get their data from different domains.

Now, I would like to have a `single scaffold (model/controller/view)` that, depending on the domain, maps to the right DB table.

Domain A would work with a model/controller called `User` which maps internally to the db table `USER_A`, and Domain B would work with the same model/controller `User` but maps to the table `USER_B`.

I would also like to use `resource :user` in my routes to access the model the rails way.

So somehow I need to overwrite the model on initialization but I am not quite sure how to go about it.

How would one go about this using Rails ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a multitable DB ready to test with, so this is an educated guess at the solution:

```
# respective models
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class DomainAUser < User
  self.table_name = "USER_A"
end

class DomainBUser < User
  self.table_name = "USER_B"
end

# controller
def set_user
  @user = if request.subdomain(0) == "DomainA" 
            DomainAUser.find(params[:id])
          else 
            DomainBUser.find(params[:id])
          end
end
```

Edit: Here's an alternative bit of metaprogramming hackery which does the subclass instantization within the parent class itself. Tested and working.

I really wouldn't want to maintain something like this though.

```
# model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.for_domain(domain_suffix)
    class_eval "class DomainUser < User; self.table_name='user_#{domain_suffix}'; end"
    "User::DomainUser".constantize
  end
end

# controller
User.for_domain("a").new
```

Comment: Doing it like that you would not need the User class. Currently doing it that way however it is not very dry ....

Comment: @mahatmanich: The only thing in the subclasses should be the `self.table_name` call. All the validations / relationships / etc. should go into the parent `User` class. How do you consider it non-DRY?

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is to have One Model, One Controller mapped as resource in routes.

Sort of like a pseudo MTI, since I really should use STI but I am not allowed to change the DB structure.

Comment: @mahatmanich: Don't think it's possible to define `table_name` after initialization, so here's an alternative which does it in the model itself. Would recommend the first method though.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help out. Currently I am actually trying to make your first suggestion work and see how it works out.

Comment: Ok I am giving up on that thanks for the help but I will need to use an MVC construct for each table. Thanks for the help.